# Using Fuerte and Groovy in the same machine?

Tags: ros, installation, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I know this question have been asked before here http://answers.ros.org/question/10660/what-happened-if-i-install-two-version-of-ros/ but, given it was almost 2 years ago, I just wanted to make sure if is still valid.
When installing ROS Fuerte and Groovy in the same machine will show any conflicts?
Other than source my setup.bash should I have to have something else in consideration?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74167/using-fuerte-and-groovy-in-the-same-machine?/) by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you do not mix up the environment setup, this should work without any problems. It's also possible to start some nodes in a fuerte environment and others in a groovy environment and have them communicate. We actually did that in routinely for our entry in the Virtual Robotics challenge, starting the Gazebo based Atlas robot simulation in a fuerte environment and running all our software in a groovy environment.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3